# $wpdb->get_var returns 0

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I use following code to get a number :

```
$where = 'WHERE type = 4 AND active = 1 AND user_id = ' . $user_id ;
$user_followed = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM {$wpdb->tablex} {$where}");
```

But it returns 0 (zero). What is the problem?

Comment: It's impossible for anyone here to tell you why a query to your own custom data isn't working. As far as anyone cal tell from this question, you're getting 0 because that's the correct response. If it's not then you need to put something in the question that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your count for that query may be 0. Make sure `$wpdb->tablex` is correct.

Also, definitely use `$wpdb->prepare`

```
$user_followed = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM {$wpdb->tablex} WHERE type = %d AND active = %d AND user_id = %d", 4, 1, $user_id ) );
```

Comment: No it is not 0. Because I tested it on mysql and it gives right number. I tried your code but still generates 0. Following code works to count comments without problem. But I can not get right number when I use different table and coumns :

        $where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = ' . $user_id ;
        $comment_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM {$wpdb->comments} {$where}");

Comment: The code you posted should work fine. Without the data from the table or the surrounding code, there's not much more I can tell you. Try using `$wpdb->get_results` instead of `get_var`.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. But it doesnt work and I don't know why it is not working. Table name is definitely right, column names are definitely right, but still same.